# Allow UILabel to truncate text, but at word boundary

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I use a `UILabel` to show text, for example:

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 100, 50)];
label.text = @"I love Apple very much";
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

But when my label is too short, the text will be truncated by default:

> I love Apple ve...

I want the text to truncate, but keep whole words, and keep frame size:

> I love Apple...

Or:

> I love Apple very...

How can I do that?

Comment: Please take a moment and look at the docs for UILabel.

Comment: @rmaddy: Do you understand my question? I want my label end with "..." and word wrapping. What document about UILabel talk about that? Do you understand?

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
myLabel.linebreakmode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

I'd also recommend going through Apple's docs, or simply Cmd+Click an Object to view it's header file and read through comments.

Comment: i think `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` it is default `linebreakmode`

Comment: I'm guessing the author has changed it to a value other than that. Common newbie mistake? Let's wait to see what the author has to say.

Comment: I only want it show on one line. If I set myLabel.linebreakmode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping; it not have "..." . I want truncate with "..." at the end, and has word wrapping.

Comment: Set the numberOfLines property on your label to limit the number of lines you want. Note: 0 is unlimited theoretically. If you only want a line: set it to 1. If you want two lines, set it to 2, and so on.

Comment: This does not both truncate _and_ apply an ellipsis. The OP is asking for an ellipsis, but only at word boundaries.